# Xcode Server Simulator Times Out Waiting 120 Seconds

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, bots, osx-server

I'm working on getting up and running with Xcode Server for Continuous Integration. I'm running Xcode 6.3.2 on my development machine, and have OS X Server 4.1 running on an iMac with the latest version of Yosemite. I've created a bot for my project, but every time it runs I get an error stating the following:

> Bot Issue: error. Uncategorized. Issue: Test target Tests encountered
>   an error (Timed out waiting 120 seconds for simulator to boot, current
>   state is 1. If you believe th. Integration Number: 18. Integration
>   URL: https://ucs-imac.slcb.uc.edu/xcode/bots/B6CBA97/integrations
>   Description: Test target Tests encountered an error (Timed out waiting
>   120 seconds for simulator to boot, current state is 1. If you believe
>   this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at
>   /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Integration-22c44be172594e54917e9723b9116f90/Session-2015-06-15_18:17:02-ukAljH.log).

I've seen several similar issues related to Jenkins and other third party CI servers. One of those discussions can be read here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1040016#1040016.

However, since I'm using OS X Server with the Xcode Service, I'm not sure why any type of workarounds would be required. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I forgot to provide any relevant info please let me know and I'll get it posted as well. Thanks

Comment: Hey! Did you ever find a solution for this? I have a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003556/xcode-7-0-1-bots-and-server-5-0-4-test-target-xx-encountered-an-error-tim